# Converting base64 string back to image in React

Tags: reactjs, base64, react-component

I'm trying to convert an image that has been changed into base64 on the backend service of my app back to an image on the frontend but seem to be running into a wall in terms of doing so. This is what I have for my code:

`PhotoContainer.jsx`

```
class PhotoContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = { photo: null };
    }

    async getUserPhoto(accessToken) {
      try {
        const photoResp= await requestAWSGet('path/to/api', undefined, accessToken);
        CachingService.setData('photo', photoResp);
        this.setState({ photo: photoResp});
      } catch (err) {
        log.error('AWSPost /api error:', err);
        throw err;
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <PhotoComponent photo={this.state.photo} />
      );
    }
}

export default PhotoContainer
```

`PhotoComponent.jsx`

```
const PhotoComponent = props => (
    <>
        {`data:image/png;base64,${props.photo}`} alt={'photo'}
    </>
);

export default PhotoComponent;
```

An example of a component where I would call the `PhotoContainer,jsx`

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <Container>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Img src={<PhotoContainer />} alt={'photo'} />
                    <Card.Body>
                         <p>Some text</p>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Am I somehow using the conversion line wrong in the component or is there a deeper issue with the way I'm setting up my container?

Answer (score 2):

You need to refactor PhotoComponent this way

```
const PhotoComponent = props => (
    props.photo ? <Card.Img
      src={`data:image/png;base64,${props.photo}`}
      alt={'photo'}
    /> : ''
);
```

export default PhotoComponent;

The ExampleComponent would need to just instance PhotoContainer

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <Container>
                <Card>
                    <PhotoContainer />
                    <Card.Body>
                         <p>Some text</p>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

You can leave PhotoContainer as is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a reason why the way I did it didn't work?

Comment: The reason why your code wasn't working is because you were passing to src a Fragment element in the short syntax instead of passing to it a string.

Comment: I would also like to reuse this in another component where the img is not a boostrap card image. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just create your own img component, you could either use a plain <img /> and add some styles to it if you like.

Comment: No I am still having trouble using props with the container for some reason. I will edit the question above

Comment: That would be a different question right? Main problem here was that the base64 was not being set properly.